# Using the word "interchangeably"

Tags: writing-style

I have a sentence where I want to say I will use couple of terms to refer to the same thing. Is the first sentence correct? or do I need to clarify that they convey the same meaning as in the second sentence?

> Throughout the paper, we will use the terms: X, Y, and Z
>   interchangeably.

OR

> Throughout the paper, we will use the terms: X, Y, and Z
>   interchangeably, but they convey the same meaning.

Comment: The second sentence is tautological (meaning it includes a useless restatement of something that has already been said). If you are using words, or placeholders *interchangeably*, then by definition, you expect them to convey the same meaning. The first sentence reads fine.

Comment: Gay is right, but note that in *technical* writing, a certain amount of redundancy of information is considered desirable to aid reader retention.

Comment: The colon should not be used for listed items in running text.